# SVG - center dynamic text within svg elements / blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, svg

Looking for the solution that will allow me to easily manage the dynamically injected text (with unknown length) in the svg rect / circle area.

Currently, designer generates for me svg via using AI and other design software. 
In generated code, the position of the text elements is determined by coordinates what means that each and every text length change forces the developer to change coordinates manually to keep appropriate alignment.

Is there a generic way to be independent of the length of the text and always align it properly in the middle (horizontally and vertically)?

Below code example and its visualization.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1106.3 443" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1106.3 443;" xml:space="preserve">
<style>
        .rect-header { fill: #AAA; }
        .rect-bg { fill: #CCC; }
    </style>

    <rect class="rect-header" width="1106.3" height="39.9"/>
    <rect y="39.7" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
    <rect y="72.4" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
    <rect x="553.2" y="39.7" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
    <rect x="553.2" y="72.4" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>

    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 525.1992 25.7028)">HEADER</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 235.1992 60.7028)">48.1</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 815.0431 60.7029)">103</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 810.2572 93.731)">ABC</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 229.0706 93.7309)">DEFG</text>
</svg>
```

[SVG example visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gll4.jpg)

Comment: Why don't make it with html/css? It is simple table, why do you want to use svg here?

Comment: I supposed that such a question may be asked. 
Above code is just an example (the easiest way to present it here) but the concept should be the same I guess for more or less complex visualizations having simple as well as non-standard shapes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `text-anchor="middle"` to specify that the text should be centred on the coordinates you supply, rather than start there.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 1106.3 443">
  <style>
    .rect-header { fill: #AAA; }
    .rect-bg { fill: #CCC; }
  </style>

  <rect class="rect-header" width="1106.3" height="39.9"/>
  <rect y="39.7" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
  <rect y="72.4" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
  <rect x="553.2" y="39.7" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>
  <rect x="553.2" y="72.4" class="rect-bg" width="553.2" height="32.7"/>

  <g text-anchor="middle">
    <text x="553.2" y="25.7">HEADER</text>
    <text x="276.6" y="60.7">48.1</text>
    <text x="829.8" y="60.7">103</text>
    <text x="829.8" y="93.7">ABC</text>
    <text x="276.6" y="93.7">DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specially need to put the text INSIDE the Svg, you can make the parent `postion: relative;`, inside it, center the svg with `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` and the same for the text in a global div, it will center no matter the size of the elements.

However, if you want to have the text inside the SVG, i'm sorry, i can't help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem with absolute position is when you want to take care of proper scaling and responsiveness. Isn't it?

Comment: Not really, it's always centered with this combination of top, left and translate. Here's a fiddle to show you : https://jsfiddle.net/gr41sp4j/ For sizing issues, i'm pretty sure you're right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The SVG `viewBox` size is important. That determines the relative scale. You can see each interior `<rect>` is sized relative to the viewBox. Total viewBox width is 1106.3, so each rect is half of that at 553.2.

You can add `<tspan>`'s inside of your `<text></text>` tags. Set your tspan x and y values starting with 1/2 the viewBox size, less 1/2 the font size. This may require a little tweaking before you get it just right. SVG uses `text-align` and `text-anchor` style tags for placement (not position:relative / absolute). Try "text-align: center; text-anchor: middle;"

Often SVGs are created in Adobe Illustrator, Sketch, or other visual applications. As a developer, I often make edits directly in the XML, carefully cutting unnecessary styles, transforms, etc. Don't be afraid to round some numbers, provided you test everything before pushing your code.

I'm an Ubuntu user, so I use Inkscape (which is also available for Mac and Windows). It's a great tool for this, offering a visual layout with a built-in XML editor and properties editors.